# Resizing multiple objects in PowerPoint - Strange enlargement

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I'm trying to enlarge multiple objects simultaneously in PowerPoint. To do that, I selected all the objects and I enlarged only one of them; the result is below.
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=24074297391927060404) the file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try grouping the objects together before enlarging them

Comment: Hello @cybernetic.nomad more or less your solution is good; the blu rectangles are enlarge to much with respect to the original one and the numbers are slightly shift with respect to the ticks.